# Does Time Machine exclude nothing by default?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I remember when Time Machine used to intelligently exclude files.

Haven't used it for a few years. Just set it up again, and it's been backing up crazy amounts of data every hour.

After some exploration, it looks like it's been backing up things like Library/Caches, ~/Library/Caches, Backblaze's bzpkg file (supposed to be auto-exluded), Docker vm image. What's crazier, after I interrupted one of the backups, I noticed that the next one (a few minutes later) reached like 150 thousand changes. And those changes seem to be Time Machine backing up its own interrupted backup under /Volumes???

What happened, why is it suddenly completely steamrolling everything without any sensible exclusions? What am I missing? Should I manually add everything? Is there a config file missing somewhere?

---

- Ventura 13.0
- M1 Max 64GB RAM, 2TB SSD
- Time Machine via carefully configured Samba share